# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '|' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/fsphp/vendor/coffeecode/cropper/src/Cropper.php

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I have some symphony vendor syntax errors when I'm trying to get composer to install my project.
Here the php version of phpinfo()

XAMPP 7.4.28-1
Linux Manjaro

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1",
    "ext-pdo": "^7.1",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0",
    "league/plates": "v4.0.0-alpha",
    "matthiasmullie/minify": "^1.3",
    "coffeecode/uploader": "^1.0",
    "coffeecode/cropper": "^1.0",
    "coffeecode/optimizer": "^1.0",
    "coffeecode/paginator": "^1.0",
    "coffeecode/router": "^1.0"
  }
```

---

```
/**
 * @param string $image
 * @param bool $unlinkImage
 * @return string
 */
public function toWebP(string $image, $unlinkImage = true): string
{
    try {
        $webPConverted = pathinfo($image)["dirname"] . "/" . pathinfo($image)["filename"] . ".webp";
        WebPConvert::convert($image, $webPConverted, ["default-quality" => $this->quality]);

        if ($unlinkImage) {
            unlink($image);
        }

        return $webPConverted;
    } catch (ConversionFailedException) {
        return $image;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you ran a Linux version on a Win PC, but I'm not sure. Please show us more details, for example, what is the PHP version of your machine? What OS do you run your project?

Comment: I see there no WebPConvert dependency on your compser.json. If so then install it: `composer require rosell-dk/webp-convert`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked yes, after installing I had to give permission on the htdocs folder and it is working. Thank you very much!